# uitableviewcell not updating image outside of cellforrowatindexpath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom UITableviewCell with an image in it.

There is a change that occurs in the app requiring the image to be updated to something different, so I am using this code in the method that handles it:

```
// Update cell
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.feedTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];

NSLog(@"%@", cell.userNameLabel.text);

cell.sampleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_sample.png"];

[self.feedTableView reloadData];
```

I added the NSLog to show that CustomCell *cell is actually pulling the correct cell. It outputs the string exactly as I would expect, but setting the image is doing nothing.

Any idea why this wouldn't be working? Another section in my app uses the same method and seems to work just fun. Picking it apart has not helped. Thanks!

Comment: maybe this is a dumb quesiton, and please excuse if so, but is the tableview pulling data from some array when you first populate it?  are you updating the value for the sample image in that array as well?

if not, you're updating the image and then immediately overwriting it with the original image from the datasource.  Yeah?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all! The image is actually a generic placeholder and once the user perform a task, the image is updated to reflect that change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code will not work because you are reloading your table. Reloading your table will override what you have did in the line before it as it will call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again

Try to save that images in an array and then read from that array in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: I think I did not explain this correctly, because you make a great point but my application is not set up to do so. With that being said, you just answered my question for me indirectly and I now have a solution. Basically I zoned out and forgot that calling reload tableview goes through the complete cellForRowAtIndex path method. I now know what I have to do, so thank you very much!